# Search with Detailed Page Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have search page which contains main title list(Like Topic1, Topic2, etc). Each topic has its own description, subtitle, etc,. So when we search the title then it will searches corresponding title. After that when we click on that searched topic then it should go to its detail page.

For example, When we search Topic2 then it will give Topics title as search result. After that If we click on Topic2 then it should navigates to Topic2 detail page.

Any help to achieve this?

**Note :** I am using Ionic3

Thanks.

Comment: This is a basic use of the Ionic navigation. Check the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation)

Comment: I have checked this already and its not exactly what I am looking for. Its not for navigation. Its for search with navigation.

Comment: Same like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189365/how-to-search-title-of-the-elements-in-navigation-using-searchbar-in-scriptionic          
But its not working for me.